# Hive -character '<EOF>' not supported here

Tags: hive, eof, parseexception

Select * from mytable where field=
'**ce7bd3d4-dbdd-407e-a3c3-ce093a65abc9;cdb597073;7cf6cda5fc**'

Getting Below Error while running above query in Hive
FAILED: ParseException line 1:92 character '' not supported here

Answer (score 2):

`<EOF>` here means End Of File. When you get an "unexpected End Of File" error it means the parser reached the end of the query unexpectedly. This typically happens when the parser is expecting to find a closing character, such as when you have started a string with `'` or `"` but have not closed the string (with the closing `'` or `"`).

When you come across these types of errors it is good to check that your query can be parsed correctly. In addition, the error gives you the location where the parser failed: `line 1:92` in this case. You can usually look at this location (character 92 of the query) and work backwards to find the problem character.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the database name to the "from" statement as below.

```
Select * from my_db_name.mytable where field= 'ce7bd3d4-dbdd-407e-a3c3- 
ce093a65abc9;cdb597073;7cf6cda5fc';
```

Hive uses the default database when no database was previously specified.